# Receiving a null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, call, extends

I have a class that sets up an array. Another class extends this class and uses the mentioned array in a method to return another array. I am receiving a null exception when I do this however when I set up the original array, it works just fine. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Still pretty new at this.

The class that sets up the array (part of it):

```
public class InitialGrids { 

int iic,ioc,iman ;
int nic, noc;
double masIC, masOC, masMAN;
double volIC, volOC, volMAN, volP;
double radIC, radOC, radP;

public int iMat[ ];
public double rad[ ];
public double vol[ ];
public double mas[ ];
public double dmas[ ];

public double [ ] radius(int nr)
{
    rad = new double [nr +1];

        for( int k = 0 ; k <= nic ; k++ )
        {
            rad[ k ] = radIC * ((double) k / nic);
            System.out.println("the radius at shell " + k + " is " + rad[k]);

        }

        for( int k = nic + 1 ; k <= noc ; k++ )
        {       
            rad[ k ] = radIC + ( (radOC - radIC) * ((double) (k - nic) / (noc - nic)) );
            System.out.println("the radius at shell " + k + " is " + rad[k]);

        }

        for( int k = noc + 1 ; k <= nr ; k++ )
        {
            rad[ k ] = radOC + ( (radP - radOC) * ((double) (k - noc) / (nr - noc)) );
            System.out.println("the radius at shell " + k + " is " + rad[k]);

        }   

        return(rad);
}
```

This is the class that extends InitialGrids(part):

```
public class Compression extends InitialGrids {

double G;
double PI;
double Pave;
double x, z, dy, dz, dydx; // this is for the iteration that will update the density
double delta;
double mix;

public double grav[ ];
public double P[ ];
public double rhon[ ];
public double radn[ ];

public double [ ] gravity( int nr ) 
{
    G = Constants.PI;
    PI = Constants.PI;
    grav = new double [ nr + 1 ];

    for(int k = 1; k <= nr; k++)
    {
        grav[ 0 ] = 0;
        grav[ k ] = ( (G*mas[k]) / (Math.pow(rad[k], 2)) ); 
    }
    return(grav);
}
```

I am calling these in the main class like:

```
    InitialGrids ig = new InitialGrids();
ig.setup(icMat, ocMat, manMat, nr, masP, fic, foc, fman, fSi, fSi, fO);
 ig.material(nr);
 ig.radius(nr);
 ig.density(nr,fSi, fSi, foc);
 ig.volume(nr);
 ig.dmass(nr);
 ig.mass(nr);

   Compression com = new Compression();
   com.gravity(nr);
   com.pressure(nr);
   com.newDensity(nr);
   com.radn(nr);
```

Comment: Could you please show the stack trace?

Comment: You mean all of the statements in my main class that call these methods?

Answer (score 0):

"mas[]" is not initialized anywhere in your code.  Unless you are initializing it elsewhere, that's your issue.

Comment: Yeah it is elsewhere. I didnt think I should be adding massive blocks of code for ya guys to sift through

Answer (score 0):

So, you're breaking nearly every rule here.  For one thing, the field `rad` is not initialized until you call a method radius, so newly created instances of `InitialGrids` are invalid until this method is called.

So your null pointer is happening because you create an instance of `InitialGrids`, `ig`, and call `radius`, and then a *separate* instance of `Compression` and somehow expect the `rad` in that instance to be related to the one in the `ig` instance?  I don't think so.

Why are these classes in an inheritance relationship anyway?

Comment: I didnt add the whole deal but, I call the radius method in the main class and below that I call the compression methods. Compression needs to extend initial grids because so many dependencies come from the initial grids class. Seemed like a simple way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, instance variable mas and rad should be initialized.
May be you need to call like this.

```
Compression com = new Compression();
com.setup(icMat, ocMat, manMat, nr, masP, fic, foc, fman, fSi, fSi, fO);
com.material(nr);
com.radius(nr);
com.gravity(nr);
```

The instance named "com" and "ig" is totally different.

Comment: So rather than initializing like: ig.setup(...) I should initialize it with com.(..)?

Comment: ig and com share a base-class.  They do **not** share values.  Any modifications you do to the values of one will have *no impact* on the values of the other.

Comment: Well I had a feeling that would happen so I set it up to where I wouldnt change the arrays I set in Initial Grids. I just need the same values to calculate for new arrays in the Compression class